Views not picking up custom field plugin in views UI
I want to create a views field plugin. At the moment, I just want to display "Hello world".
I have a custom module "lazy_admin".
This is lazy_admin.info.yml
name: 'lazy_admin'
type: module
description: 'Misc code'
package: Custom
core_version_requirement: ^10
dependencies:
  - drupal:views

This is my views plugin class OpenTickets.php (web/modules/custom/lazy_admin/src/Plugin/views/field/OpenTickets.php)
<?php

namespace Drupal\lazy_admin\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ResultRow;

/**
 * @ViewsField("open_tickets")
 */
class OpenTickets extends FieldPluginBase {

  /**
   * Defines how the field is displayed.
   *
   * @param ResultRow $values
   *
   * @return mixed|string
   */
  public function render(ResultRow $values) {
    return $this->t('Hello world');
  }
}

When I enable the module and clear the cache, I expect to be able to select the plugin in the views UI here (I'm using gin admin theme):

But I cannot find the new field anywhere.
I'm probably missing something obvious, or fundamentally misunderstanding something.
I'm using Drupal 10.2 & PHP 8.2.

It's a bit more complicated than that - so far you've created a field handler, not a field. Next step is to assign that handler to one or more fields; exactly how you do that depends on the desired outcome and what the data relates to. What is "open tickets" at its core? Does it represent a field on a content type? Or is it "virtual", e.g. a bundling of data from a few different fields? Or is to more higher-level than that; generic to any entity type, or maybe just a single global value without context?

Thanks for your comment. It cleared a lot of things up. It seems there was something fundamental I was missing (what you said).

You have to add the field to views data:
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['views']['open_tickets'] = [
    'title' => t('Open Tickets'),
    'help' => t('Display open tickets.'),
    'field' => [
      'id' => 'open_tickets',
    ],
  ];
}

Use $data['views'] to add a global field. Replace 'views' with the entity type ID if you want to add the field to a specific entity.

Thank you! This is working as expected now. I also had to override query() in my class with an empty method.
